# R data.table change R names

Tags: r, data.table

I created small data.table `DT = data.table(a=1:2, a=1:2)`.

If I use `names(DT) <- c("b","b")`

I get a warning

```
In `names<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, value = c("b", "b")) :
  The names(x)<-value syntax copies the whole table. This is due to <- in R itself. Please change to setnames(x,old,new) which does not copy and is faster. See help('setnames'). You can safely ignore this warning if it is inconvenient to change right now. Setting options(warn=2) turns this warning into an error, so you can then use traceback() to find and change your names<- calls.
```

But if i use `setnames(DT, names(DT), c("b","b")`, then I get error

```
Error in setnames(DT, names(DT), c("b", "b")) : 
  Some duplicates exist in 'old': a
```

If the same example do with data.frame than `DT = data.frame(a=1:2, a=1:2)` and use  `names(DT) <- c("b","b")` then I get no error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 37):

Don't provide `old` and `new` and you won't have a problem. However, that's not the issue. In `base::data.frame` you can't have columns of the same name so...

```
#  What you actually get...
DT = data.frame(a=1:2, a=1:2); names(DT)
#[1] "a"   "a.1"
```

But it seems that in `data.table` you can have columns of the same name...

```
DT = data.table(a=1:2, a=1:2); names(DT)
[1] "a" "a"
```

But `setnames` throws an error, I guess because it doesn't know which column `a` refers to when both columns are called `a`. You get no error when going the `data.frame` to `data.table` route because you do not have duplicated column names.

Firstly I'd say don't make columns with the same name, this is ***a really bad thing*** if you plan to use your `data.table` programmatically (but as @MatthewDowle points out in the comments, this is a design choice to give the user maximum freedom in `data.table`).

If you need to do it then use `setnames` with just the `old` argument given, which will actually be treated as the `new` names when `new` is not given. If you pass in `old` names *and* a vector of new names the old names are found and those changed to the corresponding new name (so `old` and `new` have to be the same length when `setnames` is used with 3 parameters). `setnames` will catch any ambiguities via:

```
if (any(duplicated(old))) 
           stop("Some duplicates exist in 'old': ", paste(old[duplicated(old)],
                collapse = ","))
if (any(duplicated(names(x)))) 
           stop("'old' is character but there are duplicate column names: ", 
                paste(names(x)[duplicated(names(x))], collapse = ","))
```

When *just* `old` is supplied `setnames` will reassign the names from `old` to the columns of `DT` column-wise using `.Call(Csetcharvec, names(x), seq_along(names(x)), old)`, so from first to last...

```
DT = data.table(a=1:2, a=1:2)
setnames(DT, c("b","b") )
DT
#   b b
#1: 1 1
#2: 2 2
```

---

Addition from Matthew as requested.  In `?setnames` there's some background :

> It isn't good programming practice, in general, to use column numbers
>   rather than names. This is why setkey and setkeyv only accept column
>   names, and why old in setnames() is recommended to be names. If you
>   use column numbers then bugs (possibly silent) can more easily creep
>   into your code as time progresses if changes are made elsewhere in
>   your code; e.g., if you add, remove or reorder columns in a few months
>   time, a setkey by column number will then refer to a different column,
>   possibly returning incorrect results with no warning. (A similar
>   concept exists in SQL, where "select * from ..." is considered poor
>   programming style when a robust, maintainable system is required.) If
>   you really wish to use column numbers, it's possible but deliberately
>   a little harder; e.g., setkeyv(DT,colnames(DT)[1:2]).

[As of July 2017, the note above no longer appears in `?setnames`, but the issue is discussed near the top of the FAQ, `vignette('datatable-faq')`.]

So the idea of `setnames` is to change one column name really easily, by name.

```
setnames(DT, "oldname", "newname")
```

If `"oldname"` is not a column name or there's any ambiguity over what you intend (either in the data now or in a few months time after your colleagues have changed the source database or other code upstream or have passed their own data to your module) then `data.table` will catch it for you. That's actually quite hard to do in base as easily and as well as `setnames` does it (including the safety checks).

Comment: +1 Yes it's deliberate that you can have columns the same name in data.table. And spaces and special characters and latex in columns names. For presentation formatting. But as you say duplicates aren't recommended. Sometimes handy though.

Comment: The idea of `old` and `new` is that you can change one name, by name, really easily. If that old name isn't there or is duplicated, then `data.table` will catch your error for you.  That's safer than using column numbers. And actually quite hard in base to do as well as `setnames(DT,"oldname","newname")`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle feel free to edit to make it clear *why* `data.table` gives you this power and why it's handier than `base`. I think this is a really useful feature.

Answer (score 10):

`setnames` can be used for changing multiple column names at once:

```
setnames(DT, old = c("oldname1", "oldname2", "oldname3"), new = c("newname1", "newname2", "newname3"))
```

Comment: The OP provides an example and has a specific question about it, which this answer does not address. While what you wrote is useful to know, you should read the full question before deciding where to post.